# Can we dynamically link the "People" modern web part inside with a sharepoint group

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, user-profile, modern-experience, modern-pages

I have created a new modern page inside our sharepoint online classic team site. and inside the modern page, i have added the "People" web part,as follow:-

[image]

Where inside this web part i can manually add users to it. but my question is, if i can link the "People" web part with a sharepoint group? So adding users inside the sharepoint group will automatically show them inside the "People" web part. or the other way, adding users inside the web part will automatically add them to a sharepoint group,, is this possible to achieve ?

Thanks

Comment: You could actually use 1) Flow to fetch the members of the group 2) copy it to a custom list and 3) present it by using view formatting (recently added)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No its not possible either way.

This is a first party webpart, built by Microsoft. You can only change its layout from compact to descriptive and vice versa.

For your requirement, you need to develop your own custom SPFx webpart and [consume graph APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply. But will i be able to build my own web part which will allow end users to select their desired  sharepoint group from the web part settings ? or the web part should specify the group id/title inside its code? second question, where i can host/deploy my custom web part, can i do so inside sharepoint (similar to hosting sharepoint-hosted app) or it have to be hosted on separate server (similar to provided-hosted app) ??

Comment: 1) Yes 2) yes you can host it as SharePoint hosted app

Comment: are there any helpful documentation i can follow to achieve this thing? and are you aware of any ready-made web part to achieve this requirement ..?

Comment: 1) you can check this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-manage-sharepoint-groups-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-framework-spfx/)  and follow the article to get group members 2) SharePoint by default usually packages the files used in webpart via the `"includeClientSideAssets": true,` value, so no need to worry much about deployment.